# Different keyboard-shortcut for radiolist items in dialog utility

Tags: bash, dialog, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a dialog like this:

```
dialog --no-items --radiolist "radiolist" 10 10 10 "aaa" on "abb" off "ccc" off
```

This is the dialog generated in terminal:

[image: dialog generated in terminal]

As you can see keyboard shortcut for first and second item is same - it is the `a`. Any ideas how to make the second item available under keyboard shortcut `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dialog` doesn't allow the designation of specific character positions within the list. The man page specifically states "first character" or "1-9".

However, the user can cycle through multiple list items that begin with the same character simply by pressing the same character multiple times.

In your example, pressing `a` multiple times to cycle through the first 2 items in the list is the best you can get with `dialog`